# AnySoftKeyboard ignored after update

Tags: keyboard, htc-sense

I've recently updated my *HTC One X* to version 4.2.2 of *Android* and version 5.0 of *HTC Sense*. Since then, my phone no longer uses [*AnySoftKeyboard*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard&hl=en). Even thought the `AnySoftKeyboard` option is set to `on` in the *Language & keyboard* setting, the default keyboard still opens instead of the *AnySoft* one.

I've tried uninstalling *AnySoftKeyboard* and reinstalling it, and restarting my Phone, but it still doesn't work. I've also tried following [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/wiki/HowTo), but I can't get the `Input Method` dialog to open(the tutorial is old, but I didn't find a newer one).

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have any keyboard open to enter text into an app, you should see a keyboard icon among the notifications. Click this to open the input method chooser, then select AnySoftKeyboard from the list.

The checkboxes in the **Language & keyboard** settings only control which keyboards appear in this list.